# BAD : import C types in python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I have a question when I updated my python3 to 10.4version then I got some error how can i fix it ?
is it goes different code or update the code

```
    # tipe data dari bahasa C

from ctypes import c_double
import ctypes #importdata dari c
#bisa c_double c_char


data_c_double = c_double(10,4)
print("data :",data_c_double)
print("- bertipe : ", type(data_c_double))
```

Comment: Show the full error message(s) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `c_double` takes a float parameter, should be `10.4` instead of `10,4`?